# How to create an array of mixed type in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create an array like this:

```
F.struct(F.array(struct_1, struct_2).alias('pair'))
```

When it's stored to JSON, the stored result would look like this:

```
{"pair": [{...struct_1...} , {...struct_2...}]
{"pair": [{...struct_1...} , {...struct_2...}]
...
```

Where struct_1 and struct_2 are structs of different types. But I can't do this with array because array doesn't accept mixed types. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this :

```
struct1 = StructType([
    StructField('id', IntegerType()),
    StructField('name', StringType())
])

struct2 = StructType([
    StructField('value', DoubleType())

data = [
    ( [struct1(1, 'a'), struct2(2.5)], ), 
    ( [struct1(3, 'b'), struct2(5.5)], )
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['pair'])
```